# Test automation for .NET / Java Project relying on app container

Tags: java, continuous-integration

I am looking to a testing / continuous integration tool which can help me with the following:

1) Inside a Maven project, allow me to run a JUnit test case that, using some API, deploy an application on top of a container and wait then test with the same API that the application has been correctly deployed. For this I need to launch the container through a batch file or a shell file before the continuos integration tool executes the test.

```
  public void MyTest() throws Exception {
      AdminApi adminApi = AdminApiFactory.getApi("myprotocol://localhost:1947");
      Deployable deployable = Deployable.fromFile("target/myapp.jar");
      adminApi.deploy(deployable);
      Thread.sleep(2000);
      Assert.assertEquals(adminApi.getDeployedApp("myApp").getStatus,STATUS.CORRECTLY_DEPLOYED)
 }
```

Also, after the tests have been executed, I need to shut down the container by killing the process.  The goal of such tests is to verify our assembly/packaging into jar correctness. (If one dependencies is missing in the myapp.jar, the deployment will fail )

2) Inside a .NET project, run all the .NET tests only after the the container has been launched and the application deployed. I have a client application that uses the service exposed by myapp.jar and I need to test the two in integration. I need a way to launch the container, deploy myapp and then execute these set of tests.

Comment: Welcome to SQA, Edmondo1984.  "Run a test of a .NET tests" -- can you explain what you mean by that?

Answer (score 1):

You might start with [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/).  It is free, open source, and popular, and it has a lot of extension points.  You can use it to launch arbitrary shell or script files.  A moment ago, I Googled for "Jenkins .NET" and found several articles about using Jenkins to install/run .NET applications.

Comment: I have tried with Jenkins. I had the problem of running my container script before a specific maven goal and shutting down the container just after. I never managed to find a solution